# Generator with reference not working

Tags: php, reference, generator, yield

Given the following code

```
public static function &generate($arr)
{
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
        yield $key => $value;
    }
}
```

This static method should yield $key => $value by ref on each array iteration

Then I use the static method in another class:

```
$questions = $request->questions;

foreach (self::generate($questions) as &$question) {
    $question['label'] = json_encode($question['label']);

    ... other code
}

unset($question);

die(var_dump($questions[0]['label']));
```

I should have a json encoded string but I always have an array, I don't understand why.

- The `questions` attribute in the $request var doesn't exist, it is returned by the magic method `__get` (`questions` is inside of an array so the value is returned by __get)
- If I remove the generate method and give `$questions` to my foreach, it works and I have my json encoded string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to ensure pass-by-reference "all the way through"

```
public static function &generate(&$arr)
{
    foreach ($arr as $key => &$value) {
        yield $key => $value;
    }
}
```

for both `$arr` and `$value`

Comment: Generators and pass-by-reference are quirky, and generally not recommended